# Error: $compile:tplrt Invalid Template Root

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

angular.js:14195 Error: [$compile:tplrt] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.10/$compile/tplrt?p0=uibTypeaheadPopup&p1=customPopupTemplate.html

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="customPopupTemplate.html">
<div class="custom-popup-wrapper"
     ng-style="{top: position().top+'px', left: position().left+'px'}"
     style="display: block;"
     ng-show="isOpen() && !moveInProgress"
     aria-hidden="{{!isOpen()}}">

    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="listbox">
        <li class="uib-typeahead-match" ng-repeat="match in matches track by $index" ng-class="{active: isActive($index) }"
            ng-mouseenter="selectActive($index)" ng-click="selectMatch($index)" role="option" id="{{::match.id}}">
            <a>{{match.label}}</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
</script>


<div class="form-group">
        <label for="bic" class="sr-only"  lp-i18n="bic"></label>
        <input type="text" id="bic" typeahead-popup-template-url="customPopupTemplate.html" name="bic" class="form-control" ng-class="{lpinputerror: submitted && addContact.bic.$error.required}" ng-model="contactsModel.currentContact.bic" placeholder="{{'bic'|translate}}"  uib-typeahead="item.bankBICCode for item in getBIC($viewValue)" />
        <small class="text-danger" ng-show="submitted && addContact.bic.$error.required" lp-i18n="Bic is Required"></small>
 </div>
```

Comment: Please paste some code, along with an explanation of what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: i think it can't get the template .. or there's an error in it .. can you posto more code? .. check double the path of your templates

Comment: Thank you so much for comments...don't know browser cache issue or something else....without doing anything..it's working.